# Подстановка pattern'а из html в js

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно реализовать скрипт, который будет читать атрибут pattern у input'а и подсвечивать строку красным при неверном введенном значении.

**Проблема:**
Если задать переменную pattern явно, то все работает, но если считать ее непосредственно из input`а

`var pattern = "/" + $($(this)).attr("pattern") + "/";`(с одинарными ковычками тоже не работает)

то появляется ошибка, хотя выводя данное выражение в консоль, оно в точности совпадает с тем, что я ввел явно

`var pattern = /^[а-яА-ЯёЁ0-9,.:\-+\s\x22]{0,255}$/;`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').on('input', function() {
            console.log("/" + $($(this)).attr("pattern") + "/");

            //var pattern = "/" + $($(this)).attr("pattern") + "/";/////////подстановка
            var pattern = /^[а-яА-ЯёЁ0-9,.:\-+\s\x22]{0,255}$/; ////////////явно

            if (pattern.test($(this).val())) {
                $(this).css({
                    'border': '2px solid #ebebeb'
                });
                //$('#valid').text('');
            } else {
                $(this).css({
                    'border': '2px solid #ff0000'
                });
                //$('#valid').text('Только латинские символы и цифры');
            }

    });
});
```

**html **

```
 <form method="POST" action="/expsearch">
        <input type="text" name="name" th:value="${name}" placeholder="Введите название книги" pattern="^[а-яА-ЯёЁ0-9,.:\-+\s\x22]{0,255}$" class="form-control"><br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Найти книги</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: потому что вы возвращаете строку, содержащую регуляное выражение, а `/.../` это не строка, а сама регулярка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используйте new [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)(pattern, flags) для преобразования строки в регулярное выражение

```
let regEx = new RegExp(string);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').on('input', function() {
            console.log(new RegExp($(this).val()));

            var pattern = new RegExp($(this).val());
            
            if (pattern.test($(this).val())) {
                $(this).css({
                    'border': '2px solid #ebebeb'
                });
                //$('#valid').text('');
            } else {
                $(this).css({
                    'border': '2px solid #ff0000'
                });
                //$('#valid').text('Только латинские символы и цифры');
            }

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="/expsearch">
        <input type="text" name="name" th:value="${name}" placeholder="Введите название книги" class="form-control"><br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Найти книги</button>
    </form>
```